Query text column with exactly same order in SQL Server and PostgreSQL
I have a table with same text column in two different DBMS - SQL Server and PostgreSQL.
I need query this table with exactly same order by this text column (it doesn't matter if it's in alphabetical order, it's important that it's in the same order). I need this query to compare tables content by this column.
What I need to write in ORDER BY clause?
PostgreSQL 14+, SQL Server 2008R2+
I need a solution independent of collation, OS language, codepage, text column datatype (varchar/nvarchar/text/citext/...)
I would be happy to sort by the order of some hash, but a similar question arises here - how to get the same hash value of some text in PostgreSQL and SQL Server?

"how to get the same hash value of some text in PostgreSQL and MS SQL?" You would need to make sure that the collation and data types are the same, which you explicitly seem to not want to be the same; so you can't get the same hash either.

please provide sample data and show us your desired output

I'm guessing you need to find some common collation between two systems and use it to order by it, a binary one perhaps. ORDER BY <field> collate XYZ would be the sql server syntax. This has a strong smell of X & Y problem though

When you create the tables, make sure you declare the column with compatible collations.

Or, export the tables' data and compare the files (after sorting).

"I need a solution independent of Collation" -- Well... collations define the exact ordering. If you need them to match, then you need to explicitly declare compatible collations (probably Unicode ones). Sorry, no magic bullet here.

Also, SQL Server 2008 is probably running in Windows and that sets the case-insensitive flag to true for VARCHARs. That's quite different from the rest of the databases, including PostgreSQL. Maybe you can disable that flag (temporarily at least) for comparison purposes.

I need a solution independent of Collation that won't work because the order is completely depend on the collation.

You do not need to select with the same ordering to compare them; let SQL show you the differences (much more accurate than you trying to compare them). Use the except operation to identify rows that exist in one table but not in the other (also in SQL Server). First (if it does not already exist) in Postgres create a foreign data wrapper FDW. Then use the query:
select <list_of_columns> from <postgres table> 
except
select <list_of_columns> from <sql server table>;

The result will be those values that exist in the Postgres table but do not exist in the SQL Server table; reversing the table reference would show those in SQL server not in Postgres. You can then use the known column values to identify the exact rows in each table. (See demo. I do not find a cross DBMS facility so demo simply uses Postgres to simulate).  

However, this will most likely not accommodate Collation differences. What you may be asking for is: compare different things and make them be the same.
